# OpenCL - Kernel Incrementing index of array

Tags: kernel, opencl

I want to input some values into the output array in opencl kernel based on a condition. So I want to increment the index of the array after every value input into the array. Since the condition needs to be satisfied, the output array index is unknown. I am using the output array index as an argument:

```
__kernel void match(__global float* input, __global float* output, int pos)
{ 
     if(condition)
     {
          output[pos] = input[get_global_id(0)];
          atomic_inc(&pos); // this is where the problem lies
     }
}
```

I also tried to give the pos as an array

```
__kernel void match(__global float* input, __global float* output, __global int* pos)
{ 
     if(condition)
     {
          output[pos[0]] = input[get_global_id(0)];
          atomic_inc(pos[0]); // this is where the problem lies
     }
}
```

The clBuildProgram returned with an error code -11 for both the cases. It worked when I incremented the value pos++ but that didnt return any final value of the position of the array.

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question, but let's give it a shot:

Is each element in `input` assigned a thread?  If so, `input`would be indexed using `index[get_global_id(0)]` in the kernel assuming (huge assumption) you are using a 1D array and called `clEnqueuNDRangeKernel()` with a global work size similar to `size_t Global_Work_Size[1] = {input_size}`

When calling kernels similar to the first example with `int pos`, this puts a constant of `pos` in EVERY thread, so it won't work as I'm interpreting your question.

If the kernels indexes don't map in an easy way, the index needs to be computed on the fly or another array needs to be input that is a Look-Up Table (LUT) of indexes that maps `input` to `output`.

Finally, you can use [clGetProgramBuildInfo](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetProgramBuildInfo.html) to find out exactly what the error is.  [See the write-up I did in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232846/display-kernel-error/18235334#18235334).

Comment: Sorry for not including the get_global_id(0). But yes, I want to only put those elements of input into the output that passes a certain condition. So for some thread, if the condition passes, the output array gets incremented. Is it a sequential problem that needs to be converted to parallel?

Comment: Also can you give me an idea of computing the position on the fly? In the sequential version, I used a vector and push_back() when ever the condition was fulfilled.

Comment: Hi Shunyo,

Sorry for the delay response.  The easiest way is to make the input and output arrays the same size.  If the condition is met, put the value in the output array, else put a 0 (or -1).

Beyond that, it is really tough without knowing the algorithm.  There aren't really dynamic vectors like in C++ implemented in OpenCL yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use the value of the variable that you increment using atomic_inc or you will have race conditions. The [documentation](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/atomic_inc.html) for atomic_inc mentions that it returns the old value before the increment, and if each thread uses it this way, they will each get a unique value. So the correct way to use it is:

```
int localPos = atomic_inc(&pos);
output[localPos] = input[get_global_id(0)];
```

"pos" can be a global or a local, but it seems like it should be global for your usage.